# How reliable is screen.width and screen.height?

Tags: javascript, web, resolution

I would like to make a web application with a "responsive design" to post back to the server the JavaScript screen resolution and make decisions based on that information, but the question is can I rely on window.screen to always supply the correct laptop, tablet, smartphone information?

And of course taking into consideration that it support only modern browsers and devices.

Comment: this is a browser question -- most mobile browsers report what you would expect but not all of them, all of the time. For instance, [Mobile Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) will be getting this right in the next release...

Comment: All window.screen properties are not supported across different browsers.
Width and height are reliable.
See [W3C DOM Compatibility - CSS Object Model View](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#screenview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `screen.width` and `screen.height` are reliable, however you probably would be more interested in the size of the window for laying out your pages. For instance, `@media` queries in CSS3 use the window size, not the screen size.

Comment: the media queries min or max-device-width and height refer to the screen.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about those XD

Comment: Not seems to be reliable according to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12455 ; and I can add that if you rotate your device orientation, the screen.width and height wont be updated immediately, but... like half a second later. I do not call this "reliable".